# Initialization of non constant reference from a constant reference

Tags: c++, reference

```
int main(){   
  int x = 10;
  const int&z = x;
  int &y = z; // why is this ill formed?
}
```

Why is initializing non constant reference to int to a constant reference not correct? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Surprising that most of the answers have taken example of `y=42;` below ? What's the magic number `42` ?

Comment: @iammilind: [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)), "popular culture" section - it's "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"

Comment: It's the answer to "what is six times eight?" :) [from the Hitchhiker's Guide series]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, why shouldn't it be ill-formed?

It is ill-formed because it breaks the obvious rules of const correctenss. In C++ language you are not allowed to implicitly convert the constant access pass to a non-constant access path. It is the same for pointers and for references. That's the whole purpose of having constant access paths: to prevent modification of the object the path leads to. Once you made it constant, you are not allowed to go back to non-constant, unless you make a specific explicit and conscious effort to do that by using `const_cast`.

In this particular case you can easily remove the constness from the access path by using `const_cast` (this is what `const_cast` is for) and legally modify the referenced object, since the referenced object is not really constant

```
int main(){   
  int x = 10;
  const int &z = x;
  int &y = const_cast<int &>(z);
  y = 42; // modifies x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `y` isn't `const`, you would be able to write `y = 42` and change `z` (which is `const`) too.

Answer (score 1):

Because a const reference is unmodifiable, while a standard reference is.

Comment: References are never modifiable - the things they refer to may be.

Comment: @Neil Correct, +1 for picking up on my slack/quick response.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler assumes that the thing referred to by a const int & is a const int, even though in this case it isn't. You cannot make a non-const reference refer to a const int, because you would then be able to change the (notionally) const int via the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
int const x = 10;
int const& z = x;
int& y = z;

y = 42;
```

would modify a constant variable.

Comment: But that is not what the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

As others say, it would allow one to indirectly change `x`, which breaks the const-correctness promise. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_correctness